# How to use $sce.trustAsResourceUrl together with $http service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest, cors

I have the piece of AngularJS code like below, but unfortunately it doesn't work correctly and I see "*XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://lipsum.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource*" in JS console.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
  $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
    'self',
    'http://lipsum.com/**'
  ]);
})

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $sce, $http) {
  var url = 'http://lipsum.com/';
  $http({
    url: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url),
    method: "GET"
  }).then(
    function(response) {
      console.log('success', response);
      $scope.status = response.status;
    },
    function(response) {
      console.log('error', response);
      $scope.status = response.status;
    }
  );
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZDNJ3bfO1YlRQhUmNHZj?p=preview

How to make it working correctly and getting successful response by using $http methods?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: did you try javascript's "encodeURI(url)" rather than angular escaping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming http://lipsum.com/ is the site you actually want to fetch, you can do this:

```
var url = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://lipsum.com/";
```

…and your frontend code will work as expected.

The reason that works is, it causes the request to go to `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com`, a open/public CORS proxy which will then send the request on to `http://lipsum.com/`.

And when that proxy gets the response, it’ll take it and add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header to it and then pass that back to your requesting frontend code as the response.

That response with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header is what the browser sees, so the error message the browser is showing you now goes away, and the browser allows your frontend JavaScript code to access the response.

Or use the code from https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/ or such to set up your own proxy.

The reason you need a proxy is, `http://lipsum.com/` itself doesn’t send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header, so your browser will refuse to let your frontend JavaScript code access a response from `http://lipsum.com/` cross-origin.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS has more details.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid additional proxy? E.g. for iframe $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist() works as expected but not for $http.

Comment: There’s no way to avoid the need to use a proxy of some kind as long as you’re making a cross-origin request from frontend JavaScript code to a site that doesn’t send the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header in its responses